# Sbt project depending on a external & private github repository

Tags: scala, github, sbt

[this tutorial](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/using-github-projects-scala-library-dependencies-sbt-sbteclipse) explains clearly how to have a remote github depency dependence in an sbt project using:

```
lazy val reponame = RootProject(uri("git://github.com/group/reponame.git"))
lazy val root = Project(id = "MLSS", base = file("."), settings = sharedSettings) dependsOn(reponame)
```

However if the remote repo is private, it doesn't seem to work and throws a

```
Repository not found.
Cloning into '/Users/.../b6958781f05b85672849/reponame'...
[error] Nonzero exit code (128): git clone git://github.com/group/reponame.git
```

it seems to be an auth error but how to specify the key?
thanks

Comment: I think it maybe due to a complex project with multiple sub-projects inside the remote repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just using the https version worked fine to clone the repo (provided you have the key in your sshconfig) but it doesn't add the modules to the classpath:

```
lazy val pogistan = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/group/reponame.git"))
```

Answer (score 17):

For a private repo, you want to use SSH so authentication uses your keys instead of a username & password. The github provided SSH url `git@github.com:group/reponame.git` isn't a correctly formed URI, but it's equivalent to `ssh://git@github.com/group/reponame.git`. I just tried a uri dependency on a private repo URL formatted that way and it worked for me. [Reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/simple-build-tool/Mg0ESLePfSs/OXVz9CWp3gkJ).