# In SBT, how to use addSbtPlugin with a Github URL?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

Currently, I used a plugin like this:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.tuplejump" % "sbt-yeoman" % "0.7.1")
```

But then, I fork this plugin on github (let's say `https://github.com/myname/play-yeoman.git`) and make some changes, what would be an easier way to use my forked version of plugin? Do I really have to register this fork on a maven/ivy repository?

Thanks!

Comment: What about using `lazy val  yeomanPlugin = uri("sit://github.com/myname/play-yeoman")` as mentioned in [sbt docs](https://github.com/myname/play-yeoman.git)? Are you working on a sbt plugin?

Comment: Just to complement Nader comment: [1d) Project dependency - sbt docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins.html#1d%29+Project+dependency)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using SBT 0.13.8, I was able to replace the following line in my ./project/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("net.ground5hark.sbt" %% "sbt-concat" % "0.1.8")
```

with the following two lines

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).dependsOn(concatPlugin)

lazy val concatPlugin = uri("https://github.com/ground5hark/sbt-concat.git#342acc34195438799b8a278fda94b126238aae17")
```

No other steps were necessary.  Also, note that the git URI has a commit hash on the end.  This is very useful for ensuring a known-to-work, specific version of the source is used in the project, rather than whatever the latest unknown state of the source is.

Comment: How does it work when the GitHub repo is private? How can I provide user/password or ssh key?

Comment: @mkurz, never done it myself, but this link seems to have a few solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18880397/4978821

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps:

1. Add `-SNAPSHOT` suffix to the version of the plugin, i.e. `version := "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"`
2. Run `sbt publishLocal` from the command line.
3. Reference the snapshot version from your `plugins.sbt`.