# How can I import a github project in sbt?

Tags: git, scala, github, sbt

I followed the instructions found places like here: [Sbt project depending on a external & private github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875435/sbt-project-depending-on-a-external-private-github-repository)

So in my build.sbt:

```
lazy val reflection = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/gzoller/scala-reflection.git")) 
  
lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  (other stuff)
  .dependsOn(reflection)
```

This pulled down my repo and put it in /Users/me/.sbt/1.0/staging/a9aafe45224f3cdad37a/scala-reflection
The repo looks complete.

So when I do a build on my project I get this error:

```
[info] loading project definition from /Users/me/.sbt/1.0/staging/a9aafe45224f3cdad37a/scala-reflection/project
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 128
```

Why do I get this?  The project seems to be in the right place and looks like a normal/complete clone.

Answer (score 1):

There does exist a related issue [Git source dependencies don't work on Windows #895](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/895) which seems to have been resolved, however I can also replicate your problem on my WSL machine with sbt 1.8.2 and git 2.25.1. If the directory is manually created beforehand

```
/Users/me/.sbt/1.0/staging/a9aafe45224f3cdad37a/scala-reflection
```

then it seems to work. Probably worth raising the issue again in sbt repo.